# computed attributeName in jQuery .attr() multiple method?

Tags: jquery, object, attr

i am wondering why this works:

```
var $blur = $("#blur"),
    blH = $blur.height();
    blHS = $blur.height() + 1;
    $blur.attr('data--' + blH + '-top', 'filter: blur(5px)');
    $blur.attr('data--' + blHS + '-top', 'filter: blur(0px)');
```

but this does not:

```
var $blur = $("#blur"),
    blH = $blur.height();
    blHS = $blur.height() + 1;
    $blur.attr({
        'data--' + blH + '-top': 'filter: blur(5px)',
        'data--' + blHS + '-top': 'filter: blur(0px)'
    });
```

Chrome says:

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token +

and Firebug says:

> SyntaxError: missing : after property id

I don't know what's the right syntax!!

I can not figure it out and I really appreciate any help ..

Answer (score 2):

you had Javascript syntax error, **computed property name** is not yet support, but it will be in ECMA6

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer

if you really want to do the 2nd way, this is how you do it

```
var attrs = {};
attrs['data--' + blH + '-top'] = 'filter: blur(5px)';
attrs['data--' + blHS + '-top'] = 'filter: blur(0px)';

$blur.attr(attrs);
```

Answer (score 1):

Because you can not use that syntax as an Object property.
You may use this one:

```
var obj = {};
obj['data--' + blH + '-top'] = 'filter: blur(5px)';
obj['data--' + blHS + '-top'] = 'filter: blur(0)';
$('footer').attr(obj);
```

Note that, when you get `$blur.height()` value, you can use the cashed value instead of call it again, I mean use this:

```
var $blur = $("#blur"),
    blH = $blur.height();
    blHS = blH + 1;
```

Instead of:

```
var $blur = $("#blur"),
    blH = $blur.height();
    blHS = $blur.height() + 1;
```